# Jetty Proxy ClassNotFoundException

Tags: proxy, jetty

I'm trying to configure Jetty as a proxy for http and https.
I have downloaded two different versions of jetty but I have on both the same problem.

The version that I'm currently using is: jetty-distribution-8.1.8.v20121106 running on a CentOs 6.2.

After unpacking the tar.gz, I have modified the start.ini file adding etc/jetty-proxy.xml
to the list of configuration files:

```
#etc/jetty-jmx.xml
etc/jetty.xml
<b>etc/jetty-proxy.xml</b>
etc/jetty-annotations.xml
etc/jetty-ssl.xml
# etc/jetty-requestlog.xml
etc/jetty-deploy.xml
#etc/jetty-overlay.xml
etc/jetty-webapps.xml
etc/jetty-contexts.xml
etc/jetty-testrealm.xml
```

Jetty starts regularly. I can access it on:

```
http://localhost:8080/
https://localhost:8443/
```

Reading the log file it seems that three abstract connectors have been started on port 8080, 8443 and 8888:

```
2012-12-04 12:40:03.400:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
2012-12-04 12:40:03.666:INFO:oejus.SslContextFactory:Enabled Protocols [SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1] of [SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1]
2012-12-04 12:40:03.668:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SslSelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8443
2012-12-04 12:40:03.668:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.8.v20121106
2012-12-04 12:40:03.732:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8888
```

When I configure the browser to access the proxy on port 8888, jetty fails with the following exception:

```
2012-12-04 12:40:13.463:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:Error for /search
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/client/HttpExchange
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.newInstance(ServletHolder.java:941)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:642)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpExchange
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
...
```

I have verified that the folder $JETTY_HOME/lib contains the jar file:

```
jetty-client-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
```

that contains the class org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpExchange.
To execute jetty I use the command:
    bin/jetty.sh start

The command bin/jetty.sh check returns the following information:

```
Checking arguments to Jetty: 
JETTY_HOME     =  /home/dude/Downloads/jetty-distribution-8.1.8.v20121106
JETTY_CONF     =  /home/dude/Downloads/jetty-distribution-8.1.8.v20121106/etc/jetty.conf
JETTY_RUN      =  /tmp
JETTY_PID      =  /tmp/jetty.pid
JETTY_PORT     =  
JETTY_LOGS     =  
START_INI      =  /home/dude/Downloads/jetty-distribution-8.1.8.v20121106/start.ini
CONFIGS        =  --pre=etc/jetty-logging.xml
JAVA_OPTIONS   =   -Djetty.home=/home/dude/Downloads/jetty-distribution-8.1.8.v20121106-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp
JAVA           =  /data/dude/java/bin/java
CLASSPATH      =  
RUN_CMD        =  /data/dude/java/bin/java -Djetty.home=/home/dude/Downloads/jetty-distribution-8.1.8.v20121106 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -jar /home/dude/Downloads/jetty-distribution-8.1.8.v20121106/start.jar --pre=etc/jetty-logging.xml

Jetty running pid=15498
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In OPTIONS in start.ini add client, the proxy environment requires the client artifact to be available.  Same as if you use the ProxyServlet you need to have jetty-client and its dependencies in your servlets web-inf/lib dir.

Anyway, this will show you the possible options and what makes it onto the classpath when you run it.  The start.jar really just helps build out the environment jetty runs under.

> java -jar start.jar --list-options

This will show you how things are currently setup by giving you the example command line that would be in place given the configuration:

> java -jar start.jar --dry-run

For more help on it look to:

> java -jar start.jar --help

or look here:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Start.jar